# single quotations vs double quotations

Tags: javascript, html, quotations

I'm working in javascript trying to understand when to use single quotations vs double quotations. I have noticed that when I put '' in html and then put "" in javascript for working with DOM it still works. when do I choose single quotations and when do I choose double quotaions?

ex html :

```
<p id='p1'>list of fruits</p>
```

ex javascript:

```
document.getElementById("p1").textContent = "Short list of fruits";
```

Comment: `" "` and `' '` are the same. They're both identified as a string

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the `{}` (Code Sample) toolbar button.